# how to change Escape Sequence in react to common html

Tags: reactjs

i want to precent the 1111 in html

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:"&lt;p&gt;11111&lt;/p&gt;"}}></span>
```

[image]

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:"<p>11111</p>"}}></span>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? Could you explain a little further?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to unescape HTML entities and set them with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Since there is no plain Javascript function like [`unescape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) for this, one way would be to use a [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  decodeHtml(html) {
    let parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    return parser.documentElement.textContent;
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.decodeHtml('&lt;p&gt;11111&lt;/p&gt;')}}></span>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```